# How can I make event for div in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a div in .aspx page. I have tried with javascript but i just want through C# code. so can I make event for this. Actually I want click event for this div. Is this possible or not in asp.net? Please assist me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `runat=server` with div control which will help you to create event for this. Along with you can also work clientCallBack feature of asp.net for this purpose. Both will make your work so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way,
create a button control in your asp.net page, whose visibility is none.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="BtnHiddenbutton" style="display:none" onclick="BtnHiddenbutton_OnClick" />
```

Handle the Click event of the DIV in client side like below

```
<div onclick="javascript:DivClick(); return true;"></div>

<script>

function DivClick()
{
    var BtnHiddenbutton= $('#<%= BtnHiddenbutton.ClientID %>');
         if(BtnHiddenbutton!= null)
            {
            BtnHiddenbutton.click();
            }
}

</script>
```